# How to copy all object fields into variables with the same names?

Tags: javascript, object

A JavaScript object contains a set of key/value pairs.

Given the object, is it possible for each such pair to create a variable with the same name as its key, with the value that this key is assigned to in the object?

Also, is this possible in JavaScript ES5?

For example, if the object is

```
var obj = {a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb'}
```

Then this procedure should create two variables:

```
var a = 'aaa';
var b = 'bbb';
```

Comment: Can you please provide some example input/output?

Comment: Will the keys always be strings? Will they always be unique?

Comment: This is not a good practice, but you can assign all the keys to windows and that will behave as a new  variable.

Answer (score -2):

If you know the keys in advance, you can destructure (ES6 only):

```js
const obj = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' };
const { foo, bar } = obj;
console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
```

Not recommended because global variables are bad, but you can assign the object to `window` and then reference its properties as standalone variables. This is doable in ES5 with a polyfill:

```js
const obj = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' };
Object.assign(window, obj);
console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
```

But dynamic variable names are generally a bad idea. Better to use just the object you have initially, if at all possible.

Even less recommended, but since it answers the question, you can `eval` (but please don't):

```js
(() => {
  const obj = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' };
  for (const [prop, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    eval(`var ${prop} = val`);
  }
  console.log(foo);
  console.log(bar);
})();
```

The above can also be done in ES5 if you have to, but you shouldn't have to - it's an X/Y problem

Answer (score -4):

You can use the destructuring

```js
 const obj = {a : "aaaa", b : "bbbb"};
 
 
 //use destructuring
 
const { a } = obj;

console.log(a);
```